# Bitbucket plugin can't connect in Android Studio

Tags: android, git, version-control, android-studio, bitbucket

I recently downloaded the Bitbucket plugin for Android Studio (I'm running 1.1.0). Initially, I downloaded it from this link (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6207?pr=phpStorm) which should be compatible with Android studio.

When I tried to clone a project in my repo, it prompted me for login credentials. I entered them, but it tells me that I can't connect to bitbucket. Then I installed the plugin from the plugin settings page seen here
[image: screenshot]

I made sure that the plugin was enabled. I'm thinking this is an issue that has to do with proxy settings (I'm currently on my college campuses network, but I can connect to other VCS services like Git without problems so I doubt that's the problem).

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**:
Going into Bitbucket's settings and testing it shows this:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: I'd like to clarify that I know how to use the git command in terminal and have no issues running it. I was only hoping to make the task more convenient by integrating with Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem some time ago. Though I have not yet upgraded to 1.1, I found this implementation to work with previous version:

https://bitbucket.org/dmitry_cherkas/jetbrains-bitbucket-connector/downloads

It seems the "official" one is outdated and this one is working fine.

Please, let me know if this does work for you.

Regards

Jose

Comment: I have tried that bitbucket plugin with no success. Is it possible this is an version conflict issue and I simply need to downgrade android studio?

Comment: Don't think so. I upgraded today to the latest Android Studio release and the plugin does still work. Did you uninstall the previous version prior to installing the new one?.

Comment: Yes, I did. I'm now convinced the issue might network related. May I ask if your proxy settings are manual or automatic?

Comment: My proxy settings are automatic (no proxy). I am behind my university firewall too but it will depend on its configuration. I would suggest to try a command line git client and make a small test.

Answer (score 0):

you don't really need bitbucket plugin.
**Push your project to bitbucket**
create a new repo in bitbucket
click on  "*I have an existing project*" in bitbucket repo
execute these commands in Android studio Terminal to push your project to bitbucket
**Checkout from Bitbucket**
you can also checkout bitbucket projects giving bitbucket URL in "*Checkout from GitHub*" option in Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

If you are still having problems (like I was recently) even though you've tried the plugin and you feel uncomfortable or not knowledgeable about initializing git for your project by hand via terminal you can use [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/). You will have no problems with BitBucket using source tree since both are made by [Atlassian](https://www.atlassian.com).

Once you've installed SourceTree and walked through the first boot setup process  giving SourceTree your credentials you click Clone/New and a dialog will pop up. There will be the normal browse button and also a button button that looks like a globe allowing you to browse the hosted projects linked to your BitBucket account. You can also copy an paste the link from the project home on bitbucket as well. Once you've chosen the repo you want to clone, pick the destination folder and if you want to bookmark the project or not and press "clone".

Once clowning is complete you should hit the pull button to pull down the latest changes picking the appropriate branch you want to pull from. When pulling is complete you should have all the files that's on the head of that branch (master if not specified) which in most cases is an android project.

Open Android Studio and choose File->Open and browse to the folder you just pulled data to and that open the android project. Once that is done and the project is open make sure you go to VCS and you should not see "Enable Version Control Integration". If you see this that means android studio does not see the .git folder hidden in the project root (or something in that ball park....maybe it's really not in the project root). If you see git commit and git pull options then you are now using version control and bitbucket as your remote repo. Make a change to a file and you should see it turn blue specifying that changes have been made but not committed.

For more info on version control in android studio see this video https://youtu.be/Ldmc757EXaE?t=6m47s and the documentation on the intellij website.